# Can't monitor drag event - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, drag, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some draggable `<div>` on my website.
I want to disable the drag option above a certain point on my page.

When I even just try to monitor the drag event and alert something I don't succeed.

This how I made it draggable (Divs with "screen" class):

```
//Resizable + Draggable
  let resizeOpts = { 
    handles: "all" ,autoHide:true
  }; 
  $('.screen')
.draggable()
.resizable(resizeOpts);

$('.screen')
.resizable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    alert('resizing started');
  },
  resize: function(e, ui) {

  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    alert('resizing stopped');
  }
});
console.log(arrScreens);
}
```

This when I try to monitor drag event:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("screen");
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
    alert("You dragged the element");
  }, false);
}
```

** Also if I tried addeventlistener on `body` tag I didn't success to monitor this event. On other events, it worked.

Comment: Try putting the draggable items within an element and set the `containment` property in the `draggable` options.

Comment: I didn't really get that. ```containment ``` property in CSS to the container element ? what value give it ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Not CSS, the draggable settings: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment